# Asp.net mvc & How to Apply jquery function to dynamic controls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

A bit stumped, this works for this first control but how do I apply it to the rest (list)

```
 $(function () {
        $("#spinner").spinner({
            step: 0.01,
            numberFormat: "n"
        });


    });
@foreach (var item in Model)
{<input id="spinner"  value="@item.Price" name="price_@item.Id"/>}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `CSS class` an `ID` is unique and will only pick up 1 element, a class can be applied to multiple elements:

```
$(function () {
    $(".spinner").spinner({
        step: 0.01,
        numberFormat: "n"
    });
});


@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <input class="spinner"  value="@item.Price" name="price_@item.Id"/>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the inputs a class and then setting your jQuery selector to use that class.

ie.

```
$(".spinner").spinner({
 ...
});

<input class="spinner" ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think your problem is that your code creates multiple inputs with the same ID.

IDs should be unique. Otherwise you'll have problems selecting them with Jquery.

Use a class instead.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful of duplicate html IDs, as in your example all your input elements will have the same ID. This is against the [HTML 4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id) and [HTML 5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-html5-20121217/dom.html#the-id-attribute). Either assign unique IDs as you are doing with the name, or do not assign the ID at all.

As mentioned before, assign a class to each input element and select via class selector: e.g.

```
$(".spinner").spinner({....});
```